# Find non-consecutive raw values from DB table- SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, analytic-functions

I'm looking for some analytic function in Oracle or some query which would find the non-consecutive raw values from table.

> Sample Example

```
ORDER   FLAG    |   ORDER   FLAG
6      TRUE     |    6     TRUE
2      FALSE    |    5     TRUE
2      FALSE    |    4     TRUE
1      FALSE    |    3     TRUE


ORDER   FLAG    |   ORDER   FLAG
2       TRUE    |   7      TRUE
2       TRUE    |   7      TRUE
2       TRUE    |   6      TRUE
1       TRUE    |   1      FALSE
1       TRUE    |   1      FALSE
```

So, if there's a gap values between two consecutive rows, I'd like to set  flag `'False'`- and once we set `'False'` don't need to check for consecutive values further in that column.

(duplication of values is allowed-so, `2-2-2-1-1` good; but `7-7-6-1-1` fails due to gap between 6 & 1)

Basically I'd like to flag for non-consecutive values from table.

Please let me know is there any analytic function which does this job.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [LAG analytic function](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions094.htm#SQLRF00652) which provides access to previous rows, and check if the result is equal to the value of the current row or to the value plus 1.

Comment: could you please provide an example? I checked docs.oracle- but didn't understand properly.

Comment: Sure, Oracle-Base provides some nice examples here : https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/lag-lead-analytic-functions